# Oracle WITH statement vs a dedicated table when indexes when it comes to speed

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance

I noticed when I use the oracle `WITH` statement (with the `/*+ materialize */` hint) it sometimes really can speed up queries.

However, I did notice that `WITH` is by far not as fast as using a dedicated indexed table with the same data (so in short create a table, write the data in there that I would otherwise have in the `WITH` statement and then create indexes).

Is the reason for this speed difference the fact that you can put indexes on tables and not on `WITH` datasets? Or could there be other factors like the number of rows in the `WITH` statement or the amount of memory on the database server?
Anyone knows if you can also create an index combined with the `WITH` statement?

Comment: It isn't always advisable to use the materialize hint, especially if you're only referencing that subquery once. Oracle is pretty good at determining when to materialize the subquery. Having said that, sometimes you don't want Oracle to materialize the subquery, even when it's referenced multiple times, because then you lose the benefits of indexes on the original table(s) referenced in the subquery. As with most things in the database, how you chose to access the data depends on multiple factors, such as indexes, amount of data being extracted, performance.

Comment: You have to examie an **actual** execution plan (which may be collected via EM or `dbms_sql_monitor` package), then identify places that takes too much time. Materialization may be useful when you process some small extract (filtered subset) from a large subquery multiple times. However, indexes and other optimizations may be more lightweight than materialized dataset because preducates may be pushed down to the original physical objects. So it is not "fast = true" button.There's no rule for all possible cases, optimization requires a lot of analysis.A benefit of `with` is an in-place creation

Comment: No, you cannot index WITH results, and depending on how you use that data, that may be a show-stopper. But everything depends on how you are using it, so without seeing the SQL we can't advise. There is likely a way to rewrite it so that it is performant.